# Aligning two columns of text in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to align the below code:

Sample Code:

```
.abc  (abc)
.bcd (dfdfd) 
.xyzdddddd            (xyzdfdd)
```

After alignment:

```
.abc        (abc)
.bcd        (dfdfd)
.xyzdddddd  (xyzdfdd)
```

How can we align this with Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on linux, you can call an external tool to do the job (no need for a plugin):

```
:%!column -t
```

See help `range!`:

```
:{range}![!]{filter} [!][arg]                           :range!
                        Filter {range} lines through the external program
                        {filter}...
```

Answer (score 0):

Emacs M-x align-regexp (
Does exactly what you are asking for.

Searched 'vim equivalent of emacs align regexp'
and the answer is that there is a plugin called
'easy align'
See
[www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/59uh2m/is_there_an_emacs_equivalent_to_vimeasyalign/](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/59uh2m/is_there_an_emacs_equivalent_to_vimeasyalign/)

Here is a link to easy align with instructions:
https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align